# Predict different color for same image using CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I have two white and red color image of the same shape[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6leLL.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTz57.jpg)

I labeled them as white and red. Now My ultimate goal is to predict is it has red color or white color. To achieve that i used below cnn model with 32 filters. But it predict same output for both red and white images. I noticed it works fine if the shapes are different. But i need it to work for same shape.

My Code:

```
CATAGORIES = ['red','white']
data = []

for catagories in CATAGORIES:
    folder = os.path.join(DIRECTORY,catagories)
    label = CATAGORIES.index(catagories)

for img in os.listdir(folder):
    img = os.path.join(folder,img)
    img_arr = cv2.imread(img)
    img_arr = cv2.resize(img_arr,(100,100))
    data.append([img_arr,label])

random.shuffle(data)
x=[]
y=[]

for features,label in data:
    x.append(features)
    y.append(label)

x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
x=x/255
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,padding='same',strides=(1,1),kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense( 2,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x,y,epochs=15)

img_pred = image.load_img(r'white\7.jpg',target_size=(100,100))

plt.imshow(img_pred)

img_pred = image.img_to_array(img_pred)
img_pred = np.expand_dims(img_pred,axis=0)

result = model.predict(img_pred)

print(result)

if result[0][0] > result[0][1]:
    prediction = 'red'
else:
     prediction = 'white'

print(prediction)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a CNN to do that? Maybe I'm missing the real problem here, but a very simple threshold-based method would be able to distinguish between red and white.

Comment: Btw you forgot to divide `img_pred` by 255.

Comment: @marcoromelli red could be different shades of red and white is not always pure white. sometimes similar to gray. I tried with rgb value comparison. But that was not satisfactory.

Comment: tried img_pred = img_pred/255. But still wrong output.

Comment: Convert from RGB to HSV and threshold on that. Red will be in a certain H range with high S and V. White/gray will have low V and/or S.

Comment: Can you please tell how will be HSV value for below colors if i use RGB to HSV ? "RED","YELLOW","WHITE". It could have different shades

Comment: Also how can i modify it to work

Comment: lookup "hsv color format" and "opencv image thresholding", try to make something work and make a new thread if you come across any problems